# How do I make all faces the same size?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

When I am making something in blender, I often will use an elongated square but when I do this the faces get longer and that makes it really hard to sculpt the square and I want to know if there is a way around this.

Comment: Try using the [Quadriflow Remesh Function](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html#quad)

Comment: hello you can use the Remesh tool in Sculpt mode, but if it elongates the squares you should probably activate the Dyntopo option. Also, with Dyntopo activated, keep in mind that some brushes will create new faces, some won't

Comment: Consider [Loop Cuts] to increase vertex density where you decide.

Answer (score 0):

If beginning with an elongated square, you may want to first go into edit mode and add some loop cuts by pressing `ctrl-r` and scrolling the mouse wheel up to add loops. Do this the your other axis and roll the wheel until you get perfect squares.

You can then run a few iterations of subdivide and begin sculpting.

Also: Apply Transformations before you begin sculpting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unevenly scaled a cube (or any mesh) as your start point then you should ensure you ‘Apply Scale’ to avoid warped geometry.